# poedit esc_html_e - new translation

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, poedit

I have got file `abc.php`. There was already a text there. In the languages ​​file I have a file `.pot` and `.po`. In `.po` I translated some text from abc.php. However, when I want to add some new text in `abc.php`: `<? php esc_html_e ('New text', 'abc'); ?>` the new text does not appear in the `.pot` and `.po` file.

What can I do to translate the text added by me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.pot` and `.po` files don't update automatically, you have to add the translation into the files manually.

You can just edit the `.po` file in any text editor and then generate the `.mo` with Poedit.

Comment: Yes, I made it. I changed .po in notepad like that: msgid "New text"
msgstr "Translation". But it nothing changed in text.

Comment: Are you using the right text-domain? You have now 'abc' as the text-domain.

Comment: I think yes because when I type in 'abc' the text that was previously translated in 'po' - then translates. However, when I wrote a new text in 'abc' next added it to the 'po' file then there is no change

Comment: Sorry, I made it one more time - edited 'po' and then generated 'mo' and now it works. Thank you very much :)